# use variable in psql while create tablespace

Tags: python, postgresql, tablespace

Here is the python create tablespace script, I need to use variable following LOCATION,

```
PGSQL_HOME = raw_input('Type the tablespace location path :>')

ctbsql = "CREATE TABLESPACE test OWNER tester LOCATION 'PGSQL_HOME/9.0/data/testspc';"
subprocess.Popen(['psql', '-U', 'postgres', '-c', ctbsql])
```

Of course, `PGSQL_HOME` will treat as a string, and can't take the path value, are there some other methods that I can take to create tablespace in script?

Comment: You should probably go through the [strings section](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) of the Python tutorial to learn how to concatenate strings. Further, it may be worthwhile to learn to use a database library, like psycopg2, instead of shelling out to psql.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I got you or not, if you want to get the input variable, you should uses it like this:

```
ctbsql = "CREATE TABLESPACE test OWNER tester LOCATION '%s/9.0/data/testspc';"  % (PGSQL_HOME)
```